# How to find maximum value in a column with awk

Tags: database, awk, spreadsheet

I have a file with two sets of data divided by a blank line:

```
a     3  
b     2  
c     1 

e     5   
d     8  
f     1
```

Is there a way to find the maximum value of the second column in each set and print the corresponding line with **awk** ? The result should be:

```
b 3  
d 8
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the first line of output `b 3` instead of `a 3`? If that's a typo then please [edit] your question to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on your shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
!NF{
  if(max!=""){ print arr[max],max }
           max=""
  }
{
    max=( (max<$2) || (max=="") ? $2 : max )
    arr[$2]=$1
}
END{
  if(max!=""){ print arr[max],max }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
!NF{                             ##if NF is NULL then do following.
  if(max!=""){ print arr[max],max }  ##Checking if max is SET then print arr[max] and max.
  max=""                         ##Nullifying max here.
  }
{
  max=( (max<$2) || (max=="") ? $2 : max )      ##Checking condition if max is greater than 2nd field then keep it as max or change max value as 2nd field.
  arr[$2]=$1                     ##Creating arr with 2nd field index and 1st field as value.
}
END{                             ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(max!=""){ print arr[max],max }  ##Checking if max is SET then print arr[max] and max.
}
' Input_file                     ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I get a syntax error  pointing at:  arr[$2]=$1

Comment: @RIXS, This is a tested solution, could you please copy/paste it properly(make sure `'` single quotes are also there for `awk` code) and run it. Also in place of Input_file provide your file name which you want to process by it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I put the code in a separeted awk script and it worked !! But I don't really understand what is going on

Comment: @RIXS, I have added detailed explanation for solution, in case of any queries let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this alternate `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS= '{
   max=""
   split($0, a, /[^[:space:]]+/, m)
   for (i=1; i in m; i+=2)
      if (!max || m[i+1] > max) {
         mi = i
         max = m[i+1]
      }
      print m[mi], m[mi+1]
}' file

a 3
d 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '
!$0 {
    print n
    m=n=""
}
$2>m {
    m=$2
    n=$0
}
END {
    print n
}' file
```

Output:

```
a     3  
d     8
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{cmd="sort -k2nr | head -1"} !NF{close(cmd)} {print | cmd}' file

a     3
d     8
```

runs the command for each block to find the block max.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to separate the data sets by doing:
`awk -v RS= 'NR == 1 {print}'  yourfile > anotherfile`
This will return the first data set then you change NF == 2 to get
the second data set,
and then find the maximum in each data set like suggested in
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170205/442060)

Comment: And what if I have lots of data sets and I can not change manually the NR flag, there is a way ?